# can i put a task in other task OpenERP?

Tags: task, openerp-7

i was trying to put a Task in another Task on openERP,

So all what i need to know is can i do it or not ?

Is there a Plugin that can do it ?

**Thanks.**

Comment: What was the outcome of your attempt to put a task in?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can create it. You have to use delegate. Please follow this steps.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]